# AttributeError: 'SCA_PythonController' object has no attribute 'getOwner'

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, network

I'm using v2.69 and I get this error in my terminal:

> AttributeError: 'SCA_PythonController' object has no attribute 'getOwner'

I'm using Linux.

The error in the line 21. Is the problem in my code or the version?

```
from GameLogic import * 
import GameLogic as GameLogic
#START THIS SETUP ONE TIME AS A SERVER AND ONE TIME AS A CLIENT

#BEVORE YOU START THIS SETUP AS A CLIENT REPLACE THE * IN THE 
#LINE BELOW WITH THE SERVER IP 
#(FOR EXAMPLE: GameLogic.IP = "192.123.100.1")



GameLogic.IP = "192.168.1.1"





#THE CODE BELOW SETS UP IF YOU PLAY THE CLIENT OR THE SERVER
#TO START THE SERVER PRESS F1 TO START THE CLIENT F2

cont = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
obj = cont.getOwner()
scene = getCurrentScene()
Server = cont.getSensor("F1")
Client = cont.getSensor("F2")

if Server.isPositive():
    Server = scene.getObjectList()["OBServer"]
    Server.Activ = 1
if Client.isPositive():
    Client = scene.getObjectList()["OBClient"]
    Client.Activ = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Python code written for BGE 2.49 and earlier.

You need to convert it to BGE 2.5+. This includes API changes and upgrade to Python 3.0.

To make it short:

```
.getOwner()      -> .owner
.getSensor("F1") -> .sensors["F1"]
.getObjectList() -> .objects
["OBServer"]     -> ["Server"] 
Server.Activ     -> Server["Activ"]
```

It looks like this is just a fragment of more logic.